# the project was not built...cannot find the class...org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

Tags: grails

I wrote a simple hello world project using spring security core. Basically i have a controller with one secured annotation.

```
package springsecuritytest

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured


@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class HelloController {

    def index() { 

        render "this is public"     

    }


    def logout(){


    }

}
```

So, far the app complies and works correctly. When i try to access index page then it will ask me to login and only if i have an admin role am i allowed to access the page.

Now, i add a simpe code for logout and i get the following error

```
package springsecuritytest

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils


@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class HelloController {

    def index() { 

        render "this is public"     

    }


    def logout(){

        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl

    }

}
```

The error i get is as follows:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add below two lines in your config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "/login/auth"
```

And attach the link "../logout" to logout button like below

```
<a href="../logout">Sign out</a>
```

This will do the trick. You don't have to create any action for logout handling.

Please compile, clean and then run your project.